# React - differentiating between dynamically generated inputs on a form

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have an input form for data in a table that generates inputs in accordance to how many columns there are. I am struggling to separate the inputs however so that when I change a value in one all of the inputs change. Is there any way that I can differentiate between them so that I can input different values in each input. I am using React with flux.

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class RowForm extends React.Component {
    state = {input: ''};
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({input: e.target.value});
        console.log(input);
    };

    editStop = () => {
        this.props.editStop();
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let access_token = AppStore.getToken();
        let id = AppStore.getTable().id;

        this.props.handleSubmit(access_token, id);

    };

    render() {

        let {input} = this.state;
        let dataEntries = AppStore.getTable().columns; //this gets the amount of columns so I can map through them and generate the correct amount of inputs.

        return (
            <tr>
                {dataEntries.map((element, index) => {
                    return (
                        <td key={index}><input type="text" className="form-control" id={element.id} placeholder="enter data" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
                    );
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.editStop}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i>Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit}><i className="fa fa-check"></i>Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, especially examples!

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function in the `onChange` handler:

```
<input key={index} onChange={event => this.onChange(event, index)}/>
```

However, the larger problem is that you are not mapping your `AppStore.getTable().columns` to state anywhere so you won't be able to modify the component state at all. Also, you are using ES6 classes improperly with React.

```
class RowForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputs: {0: null, 1: null, 2: null}
    };
  }

  onChange (event, index) {
    this.setState({inputs[index]: event.target.value});
  }
}
```

If you need to map `AppStore.getTable().columns` you should pass that data down as props. Mapping props to state is an anti-pattern.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () { // initialize stuff... }

  componenDidMount () {
    this.setState({columns: AppStore.getTable().columns});
  }

  onChange (event, index) {
    this.setState({columns[index]: event.target.value});
  }

  render () {
    <RowForm columns={this.state.columns} handleChange={this.onChange}/>
  }
}

class RowForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    <div>
      {this.props.columns.map(index => {
        return <input onChange={event => this.props.handleChange(event, index)}/>
      })}
    </div>
  }
}
```

However, this will not update the `AppStore` when `onChange` is called. For that you need to keep track of global state somehow. I suggest checking out [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

---

Updated answer to try and fix the code with the current conditions:

```
class RowForm extends React.Component {
  // Set `dataEntries` to an empty array. This will prevent errors
  // from appearing in between `render` and `componentDidMount`.
  // e.g.: `this.state.dataEntries.map` is undefined or not an Array.
  // You may want to make this a little bit more fail safe though.
  state = {dataEntries: []};

  onChange = (event, element) => {
      // This assumes `element` is a string based on the column name.
      this.setState({dataEntries[element]: event.target.value});
  }

  componentDidMount () {
      // Set state with columns from the table.
      // Whenever this component mounts it will reset to the state
      // from `AppStore` unless you set up event listeners like in
      // Flux or migrate to Redux

      // This also assumes that `getTable().columns` returns an array
      // of column names. I don't know what your data structure looks
      // like so it's hard for me to help here. You need to turn the
      // array into an object to store values in the keys.

      let dataEntries = AppStore.getTable().columns.reduce((obj, name) => {
          obj[name] = null;
          return obj;
      }, {});
      this.setState({dataEntries});
  }

  render () {
        let {dataEntries} = this.state;

        // It is not really recommended to use indexes here because
        // of the way React diffing works. If `element` is a string
        // you can use that as the key/index instead. Also, it needs
        // to be unique within the array.
        // Turn dataEntries back into an array so map will work properly.   
        return (
            <tr>
                {Object.keys(dataEntries).map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <td key={element}><input type="text" className="form-control" id={element} placeholder="enter data" value={dataEntries[element]} onChange={event => this.onChange(event, element)} /></td>
                    );
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.editStop}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i>Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit}><i className="fa fa-check"></i>Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using some es7 initialisers which is why I am not using the constructor from es6. I unfortunately have to build in flux for the moment, but I trying to make it so I can start using redux. Your answer did help a lot but in the onChange event how is it possible to map the index to columns? When I run my build tasks I get an error at that point?!

Comment: I updated the answer to try and help out. You will need to map AppStore to the component local state. I've shown you how to do this with comments above. I strongly suggest migrating off local state though. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer Mike! I've almost got it working but when I try and enter in data in the input, it changes from multiple inputs to a single input, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Never mind fixed it myself! Thanks again for your help!